# How do I call an Entity method from Twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

A lot of you are going to tell me that I should figure out a way to do relationships better in my tables but I have a 'products' table and a 'product_images' table which are easily joined in a query but because the path to the images can be radically different and I do not want to store path names in the table, I need a function to do some calculations to find out what the path is. I need the method to run for each product as I am iterating over each one to get the path to the image.

What I want to do, and maybe I'm not thinking correctly, is in Twig I'd like to ask for a method to run for the product Entity

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{product.getImageUrl()}}
{% endfor %}
```

which would call a method in my product Entity

```
//AppBundle:Entity:Product
public function getImageUrl()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
    return $repository->getImagePath($this->id);
}
```

In my repository:

```
//AppBundle:Repositiories:ProductRepository
public function getImagePath($id)
{
    return 'http://domain.com/path/to/image.jpg'//simplified for my question
}
```

How can I do this? When I try this at the moment, I am getting the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in product/index.html.twig at line 19.
```

where line 19 is

```
<img src="{{product.getImageUrl()}}" alt="img">
```

How can I accomplish using a method from the Entity? Or tell me how else I can do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should figure out how to do your relations better.  Just kidding.  Your twig is correct.  have Product::getImageUrl() just return a simple string to prove it.  Your product entity is all screwed up.  No way you have the container accessible in it.  You probably need something like ProductImagManager::getImageUrl($product) and then access it in twig through a twig extension.  I am assuming that you are actually passing an array of product entities and not an array of product arrays.  Which is sort of what your error message seems to indicate.

Comment: {{ product.imageUrl }} ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is right in the error message.
As it explains to you, twig cannot convert an array to a string. Now why do we even have an array?

I assume, that in your `public function getImagePath($id)` method, you call `getResult()` in the end to get the desired image path. However, `getResult` always returns an array of results, even if there is only one result.

If you are sure that you will get only one result, try calling `getOneOrNullResult()` instead, which should solve your problem